# Error in type matching Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have declared the following types

```
data MonthData = Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec deriving ( Eq, Show, Enum, Ord )
type Year = Int
type Month = ( MonthData, Year )



type Gap = Int
type Average = Double
type HistoryElem = ( Date, Gap, Average )
type History = [ HistoryElem ]
```

Then, I have declared the following function

```
event_tests = [ ( ( 28, ( Nov, 2016 ) ), 0, 0.0 ), ( ( 27, ( Nov, 2016 ) ), 0, 0.0 ) ]
history :: Int -> HistoryElem
history 0 = head( event_tests )
```

When I try to load my file, I have the following error.

```
ERROR "ass16-1.hs":90 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : history
*** Type           : Int -> ((Integer,(MonthData,Integer)),Integer,Double)
*** Does not match : Int -> HistoryElem
```

It seems that it doesn't consider that HistoryElem has been previously defined because if we look carefuly, we can see that

`((Integer,(MonthData,Integer)),Integer,Double)` is the same definition than `HistoryElem`

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where is `Date` defined?

Comment: When getting a type error, adding type signatures to all the top-level bindings can greatly simplify it. Most Haskellers do that as a best practice. Indeed, sometimes the error is found later, in a surprising place where everything looks fine -- but the real error was much earlier and was not found only because the compiler inferred a different type than the one you would expect. Using a type annotation makes the compiler report errors where they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a type signature for `event_tests` should do the trick:

```
eventTests :: History
event_tests = [ ( ( 28, ( Nov, 2016 ) ), 0, 0.0 ), ( ( 27, ( Nov, 2016 ) ), 0, 0.0 ) ]
```

Part of the issue is that, as the type error suggests...

```
ERROR "ass16-1.hs":90 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : history
*** Type           : Int -> ((Integer,(MonthData,Integer)),Integer,Double)
*** Does not match : Int -> HistoryElem
```

... `Int` and `Integer` are not the same type. As [section 6.4 of the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1350006.4) specifies, an `Int` is a fixed size integer, while an `Integer` can have arbitrary size. This affects your code because, if there is no type signature anywhere to specify which type an integer literal should be, it will default to `Integer` (see [section 4.3.4 of the report for details](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3)). That being so, integers such as `28` and `2016` in your `event_tests` default to `Integer` unless you specify some other type (e.g. through your `History` type synonym, which indirectly makes them `Int`s).